# Getting too much organic traffic? how to identify is it real or fake?

Tags: seo, google-analytics

Some days ago I used some traffic generator sites to increase traffic for my site. But after doing log out from this sites. The traffic which is coming to my site from these sites should stop, but still, traffic is coming and this traffic showing as organic traffic in analytics under not provided keywords. I also read about how to identify fake traffic. The answer is if your getting it from the same location again n again or having high bounce rate so it may be fake traffic. But there is no high bounce rate also getting traffic from a different location but most traffic is from the USA. For reference, i'm attaching my GA audience overview of today. In blogger dashboard under traffic sources Referring URLs and Referring sites are showing from google.com. Really not getting is it fake traffic or real traffic. Also checked Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders in analytics setting. I heard about captcha setting so can I add CAPTCHA before entering my site? So it will avoid bots. Please any solution as soon as possible I want to avoid it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to check weather organic traffic is real or fake, I use mostly Google search console, why? Because it is not normal analytics like Google analytics which track something when someone land in your website (including spam bot) or using http headers(Which is easy to spoof for many spammer).

To make it fake search console analytics report, your competitor or any third party tool have to search that phrase in search and also have to click on search result, which is not easy and required more CPU resource. At this time there are some tool which track keyword position, but they just check the position, and does not click on search result pages. **So you will get better assumption with number of impression and number of clicks from search analytic report.**

To see your search analytics report go to your search console, click on search traffic and finally click on search analytics. Or simply [click here](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/search-analytics) and choose your web properties. Hope you have already added your website on search console.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I checked the search analytics in search console. There are some queries showing with some keywords. But organic traffic which is coming on my site is on homepage.

Comment: It show sub pages as well on which you're getting most of organic traffic. Just tick on pages instead of query.

Comment: There is 0 click on homepage

Comment: So it means no organic traffic clicks you're getting on your homepage.

Comment: Here is one of [my search analytics reports SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ1QS.png), which show some stats number, hope it might help you.

Answer (score -1):

Go to cpanel and check the traffic analytics there . Fake traffic may be comes from same ip addresses

Comment: actually I'm using blogger for my site

Comment: This is a very short answer.  Can you add to it to make it better?